# What causes chrome to automatically install extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, malware

I have installed Chrome Beta on my computer. Immediately after opening it for the first time, it warned my about several extensions that where installed automatically:[screenshot of warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lgk10.png)

The first 3 seems OK, but the last one (Adaware Secure Search) is probably a malware. I have scanned the computer with multiple antivirus software, didn't find anything suspicious. I would like to know by what mechanism other software cause this automatic installations of extensions upon chrome installation.

Comment: Where did you download chrome beta from?

Comment: https://www.google.com/chrome/beta/, 
and this is a link to the installation file: https://dl.google.com/tag/s/appguid%3D%7B8237E44A-0054-442C-B6B6-EA0509993955%7D%26iid%3D%7B1FFC298A-1C48-313F-4F7F-1CA1EE480976%7D%26lang%3Den%26browser%3D4%26usagestats%3D1%26appname%3DGoogle%2520Chrome%2520Beta%26needsadmin%3Dprefers%26ap%3D-arch_x64-statsdef_1%26installdataindex%3Dempty/update2/installers/ChromeSetup.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installation caused by registry keys in

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Google\Chrome\Extensions
HKU\S-X-X-XX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXX\Software\Google\Chrome\Extensions
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\Extensions
```

They contain keys named the ids of the extensions (for example `lmjegmlicamnimmfhcmpkclmigmmcbeh`). Deleting a key stops the automatic installation.

Answer (score 3):

first of, this can happen when you visit some malicious or sites that do not ask your permission or asks you to perform a task

2.it can also happen during installaion of softwares, if you do not read the process and keep clicking next next, and those add-ons get installed, also, maybe you did not do that now, your previous version of chrome might have had some of those extensions installed and so were transferred to the newer version you installed.

you either have to delete all the chrome files in your C/drive and reinstall, (you may loose bookmarks/passwords if not backup) you can also reset chrome from advanced settings.
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2765944?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: I have non of these 4 extensions in the stable version of chrome